# in which situations use of positioning would be a better option than float?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How positioning can save our time if we use in place of float on some place in layout coding?

How we can judge where positioning would give better result?

[For example (i added just for example) if this is a design](http://s3.amazonaws.com/adaptiveblue_img/topics/p/website_wireframe)

So far i only use float + margin + padding, now if i can mix positioning and save time and get pixel perfection easily then float.

**Guide me**

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**

these are common elements of website. should i use positioning for any of them?

```
The Header
 ---logo
 ---serch box
 ---The Navigation Menu
 ---top links
 ---Breadcrumbs

The Text Area
 ---Paragraphs
 ---images( left , right or center align)
 ---Tables
 ---vertical ordered and unordered list

The Sidebar
 ---vertical ordered and unordered list


The Footer
 ---copyright
 ---Important Links (horizontal list)

Form elements
```

**Update 2:**

- Does positioning have any
  Compatibility issue(including IE6) than float?
- Is positioning is only good for fixed
  width design or it's good for both
  liquid and fixed?

Comment: The only compatibility issue I know of is that the parent must be relative if the child is absolute, but that is the same for all browsers, I would stay away from positioning full stop to honest with like Tatu Ulmanen says it is for special occasions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that layout, you don't need to use nothing else than floats, margins and paddings. Positioning (`relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`) should be used only in 'special occasions', eg. when you want to lift an element out of the document flow and place it somewhere it would be otherwise hard to place.

You won't save any time and won't get any more 'pixel perfect' results with positioning. You should be able to do that using traditional methods.

The only reason you should use absolute positioning in that layout is because of the RSS icon, that's a 'special occasion' I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the design there is minimal need to using positioning, the only I can see it may be need is t give the overlapping effect on the RSS icon but even then you could do some trickery with background images to give the effect that it is overlapping.

On my sites I use position if I need to give the user the experince that elements overlap outside of the box model. Otherwise you should be fine floating, padding and using margins.

One tip howerver if you are using `position:absolute;` make sure the parent element has `position:relative`;